# Flex graphic editor - samples open source projects

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I need to create an application, the main срфддутпу will be to work with graphics. The application will contain the basic operations with geometric shapes and creating your own shapes.

When creating, I would like to rely on ready-made examples of graphic editors. To do this, I'm looking for examples of open source projects.

Does anyone know any examples of similar projects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about Degrafa ?

http://code.google.com/p/degrafa/
http://jameswhittaker.com/journal/skinning-flex-with-degrafa-and-fxg